# What is binary norm of quadratic fields of sum of two squares such that one of them is necessarily even like $a^2 +4b^2?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I am trying to simplify an expression which I have reached, suppose a number can be represented in the form of $D=a^2 + 4b^2$. What is binary norm of $D$, or how else can it be represented?